# Group statement being added to query automatically in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So I'm using Laravel eloquents to access data from my database - it's very similar to other statements in my code which work fine, but for some reason this isn't working:

```
$data->leftjoin('val_keys', function($leftJoin) use (&$key_words)
{
    $leftJoin->on('val_keys.val_id', '=', 'vals.id');
})->whereRaw(DB::raw(sprintf('(LOWER(val_keys.key) LIKE "%%%s%%")', strtolower($key_words))));
```

I keep getting the following error, which shows that there is a group statement that is somehow being added to my SQL query despite the fact that I'm not putting it there:

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in group statement is ambiguous (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `vals` left join `val_keys` on `val_keys`.`val_id` = `vals`.`id` where (`category_id` = 3780) and (LOWER(val_keys.key) LIKE "%hey%") group by `id`)
```

I've tried adding my own `groupBy()` to my query, with `vals.id` as the input, hoping that this would override the group statement that uses `id`, but it doesn't:

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in group statement is ambiguous (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `vals` left join `val_keys` on `val_keys`.`val_id` = `vals`.`id` where (`category_id` = 3780) and (LOWER(val_keys.key) LIKE "%hey%") group by `vals`.`id`, `id`)
```

How do I get rid of this group statement so my query will run as intended? I've already tried changing `strict` to `true`. I am using Laravel version 5.2.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your full query? Your error message does not match your leftJoin statement.

Comment: SELECT Count is missing and the Group BY

Comment: @aynber the error message not matching my leftJoin statement is the problem. I'm trying to figure out where the hell the group statement in the error message is coming from because it's not coming from my code.

Comment: @nbk what do you mean?

Comment: Check for similar code somewhere else. By the way, the closure in your leftJoin is not necessary, since you're not using $key_words in it. You can change it to just `$data->leftjoin('val_keys', 'val_keys.val_id', '=', 'vals.id')`

Comment: @sameroach your code doesn't seem to be complete with that code you can't create  select count(*) as aggregate from `vals` left join `val_keys` on `val_keys`.`val_id` = `vals`.`id` where (`category_id` = 3780) and (LOWER(val_keys.key) LIKE "%hey%") group by `vals`.`id`, `id` and the last id is what i causing the problem

Comment: @nbk what do you mean the last id?

Comment: *group by vals.id, id *  as you see the grup by has two columns vals.id and id. and i can't see in your code anything about a group by

Comment: In order to answer your question, you need to show more of the query. You are doing a ->count() somewhere and you are not showing it. Can you show the whole query as the error is coming from elsewhere.